# Putting a notice on copied JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I have seen some of my sites fully ripped in the past (front end). Some people copy/pasted all the content including the GA tracking code :)

I was thinking to plant some kind of notice inside the JS so when someone copies it they (and their visitors) will see it. I know I can't protect front end code but if this prevents some people of using it (at least those who don't know what/where to look) then mission accomplished.

Here is what I have done so far (as Amy suggested):

- minified & obfuscated code
- copyright notice at the top

Here is a small implementation of what i would put in mix with the rest of the code:

```js
if (window.location.hostname && window.location.hostname !== 'myDomain') {
  document.body.style.opacity = '0.2';
  document.body.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  c = [84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 114, 105, 112, 112, 101, 100, 32, 115, 105, 116, 101, 33];
  alert(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, c));
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, his aperiam percipit assueverit ea, sit ei eius adhuc tacimates. Cum ad numquam rationibus, mel eu scripta aliquando. Eum ex habemus constituto mediocritatem. Ea dicam aliquip salutatus usu, vidit admodum sadipscing at mei. Alterum blandit efficiendi duo in, dicat quodsi vidisse in quo, malis latine lucilius ad est. Qui enim explicari at, est cu iusto impetus, ferri iudico similique at eos.</p>
```

Is there any more *creative* way besides what I've got now? :)

Comment: You might want to obfuscate the whole codebase. It will make it even harder to find where your protection is and make modifications extremly hard and will deter copier in the first place because they will almost always want to be able to do some minor changes.

Comment: I would suggest checking if your sites domain is within the URL instead of trying to exactly match it. What you're doing currently is probably the most common, minimalistic, and best way. Other than that the only thing I could think of is that you could try to send a postmessage and catch it.

Comment: @zfrisch what kind of postmessage do you mean?

Answer (score 6):

Your current approach is basically a ticking time-bomb waiting for you to change domains.  It's also very easy to remove.

Instead:

1. put copyright notices at the top of your code
2. minify your code
3. obfuscate your code

You cannot prevent someone from stealing your JS code. Instead, make it not worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks Amy - i forgot to mention that I've already made those steps. Still +1 as it is a must.

Comment: There's little else you can do that isn't just as likely to affect you or whomever inherits your code.  It's just not worth it.  Make it difficult to steal, make it clear what they're doing is theft (via copyright notice), and move on.

Comment: You're right but still if i can do something a little more (like alerting the message) or similar and preventing some % of people not ripping it then it's worth it.